# MVC 5 dynamic model in partial view

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a few (around 6) lookup tables like degreetype, categorytype, etc. All these table has similar column id, name and isactive fields. I created CRUD stored procedure for each table.

In my MVC5 project, i created a model, repository and DAL to pass data to sp for each.

I also created viewmodel, controller and crud views for each.

I realized the crud (create/edit/detail/list/delete) view pages uses the same html except for calling the model at the top of the page.

Question: Is there any way i can create a partial view of the html and use a dynamic model in the pages?

eg:

```html
@model Microsoft.myorg.viewmodels.degreetypesVM
<!-- need to use a dynamic model (degreetypesVM, categorytypeVM etc) above and create a partial view for the below html -->

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Degree Type";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
 <table class="container">
        <tbody>
            <tr class="row">
                <td class="col2" scope="row">
                    <div class="title-text">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
                        <span title="This field is required." class="warning">*</span>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="gray">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </td>
            </tr>
            ..
            ..
           </tbody>
           ..
           ..
```

Comment: How about creating a general viewmodel (called for example LookupViewModel) for all of them?

Comment: I have datamodel created for each table and was referenced in viewmodel. I have repositories with db actions for each one. need to rewrite general all and pass variable to differentiate between the views. so the variable goes from view =>controller=vm=>dm=>repository where it take does db operation based on the variable?

Answer (score 0):

you can simply write a partial view and pass model in it or just wrap up all common fileds 
and write their own model for your partial view